# Adding formulas to specific cells using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to add formulas to a googlesheet based on an identifier in another column.

In the below example, wherever a row has PARENT in column A, I want to add a formula in that row of column B.

I'm comfortable with what the formula needs to be - I just don't know how to identify everywhere it is needed.

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask[

Comment: Why not just regular formula's? =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A = "","",IF(A2:A = "Child",5,YOUR FORMULA HERE)

Comment: @RemcoE33 what I am trying to do is take reports - which we get from another system, and replace and computed value with the formula needed (i.e. sum of the cells below). People need to be able to edit the data (the 'Child' values) and ideally, the parents will update also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

Here are the steps:

- You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a formula array `frms`. Every element in this array will be either the fixed formula `frm` (if `Parent` is in column `A`) or an empty string.
- Please keep in mind the following approach considers a **fixed** formula. Your goal might be the formula to depend on the row the matching was detected. I am afraid that if this is your goal, you might need to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and take advantage of the `index` parameter in the `map` function.

---

### Code snippet:

Modify the sheet name `Sheet1` and the formula `sum(A1:A2)` to your needs.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data = sh.getRange('A1:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const frm = '=sum(A1:A2)';
  const frms = data.map((d,i)=> d[0]=='Parent'?[frm]:[d[1]]);  
  sh.getRange(1,2,frms.length,frms[0].length).setValues(frms); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! This has definitely got me closer. The issue now is that the rest of the data is deleted - the values of the child rows. Do you know if there is a way to do this without losing those values?

Comment: i've found a solution - have the formulas copied into a temporary column (i did need template literals) then filter the whole table then copy across the formulas. Not very elegant but does the trick. thanks again @Marios